# Get CURRENT_TIMESTAMP as part of ResultSet

Tags: java, sql, sql-server, identity, resultset

is there any way of retrieving database generated values in Java other than IDENTITY fields? I can easily get IDENTITY values from a ResultSet, but I'd like to get the value of a date field which has been generated by the database (CURRENT_TIMESTAMP). I prefer not to send another SELECT query to get the date.

```
statement = connection.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO foo (bar_date) VALUES (CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)");
ResultSet generatedKey = statement.getGeneratedKeys();
while (generatedKey.next()) {
  // read the key..., this unfortunately only returns IDENTITY columns.
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you're using SQL 2005 or later, you could add an `OUTPUT` clause to your insert statement to have it return a result set.

I'm not sure of the Java syntax to retrieve the resultset, but it would be something like the following:

```
statement = connection.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO foo OUTPUT inserted.id, inserted.bar_date (bar_date) VALUES (CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)"); //guessing the name of the id column
ResultSet returnSet = statement.execute(); // or however you do this
while (resultset.next()) {
  // resultset will have two columns - id and bar_date
}
```

Comment: Great, that works fine. I assume there is no database independent way of doing this... (such as < MS SQL 2005 or sqlite even)?

Comment: @Max - the OUTPUT clause doesn't appear to be part of the ANSI standard, so it's SQL server only. Other database engines may have their own implementations; Oracle has `RETURNING`, which Postgres also implements. There's no equivalent in MSSQL pre-2005, or in sqlite for that matter. The most portable method would be to wrap the logic up in a stored procedure which returns a result set (or output parameters) - but this won't be database agnostic because of  the differences in SP implementation in each RDBMS.

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried something like

```
INSERT INTO foo (bar_date) 
OUTPUT INSERTED.bar_date
VALUES (CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)
```

Have a look at [OUTPUT Clause (Transact-SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177564%28v=SQL.90%29.aspx)

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly what I've been looking for.